# How to get the month numbers from an array of month names in angular 10

Tags: angular, typescript

```
distYearMonths: {2018: ["Oct", "Sep", "Dec", "Nov"],…}
2018: ["Oct", "Sep", "Dec", "Nov"]
2019: ["Jan", "Jul", "Jun", "Nov", "Oct", "Sep", "Apr", "Aug", "Dec", "Feb", "Mar", "May"]
2020: ["Feb", "Jan", "Mar", "May", "Apr", "Jun"]
```

I want to show month numbers instead of names in the same above format. Can anyone suggest to me the solution?

Comment: please share also html code how u want to show it. And your variable is not valid object

Comment: simply use a dictionary. @pc_coder already suggested but you can make an object like `const obj = {
  "Jan": 1,
  "Feb": 2,
  "Mar": 3,
  "Apr": 4,
  ...
}`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62830215/how-to-get-monthname-from-number-using-angular-datepipe/62830320#62830320

Answer (score 2):

in html to show number rather than name then u can use pipe as a way

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'month'
})
export class MonthpipePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any): any {
    return Months[value];
  }

}
enum Months{
  "Jan"=1,
  "Feb"=2,
  "Mar"=3,
  "Apr"=4,
  "May"=5,
  "Jun"=6,
  "Jul"=7,
  "Aug"=8,
  "Sep"=9,
  "Oct"=10,
  "Nov"=11,
  "Dec"=12,
}
```

then in html write pipe to convert to number in html. [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a1s6wi?file=src/app/monthpipe.pipe.ts)